# Как получить имена всех установленных LocalDB?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-localdb

Как получить имена всех установленных LocalDB?

**Ввожу:**

- `sqllocaldb v`
- `sqllocaldb i`
  Получаю как на картинке.

Ожидание:

- при установке LocalDB система автоматически присваивает имена типа **MSSQLLocalDB**, **MSSQLLocalDB1**, **MSSQLLocalDB2**;
- потом пользователь вводит команду в консоль и получает **список имён** установленных LocalDB;

Как это работает?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]